# Get last duplicate element in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list contains duplicate items.

```
List<string> filterList = new List<string>()
{
     "postpone", "access", "success", "postpone", "success"
};
```

I get the output which is `postpone, access, success` by using

```
List<string> filter = filterList.Distinct().ToList();
string a = string.Join(",", filter.Select(a => a).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

I had saw other example, they can use `groupby` to get the latest element since they have other item like ID etc. Now I only have the string, how can I get the latest item in the list which is `access, postpone, success`? Any suggestion?

Comment: Um, `string.Split(a, ',').Last().Trim()`? It's not really clear to me how the background is relevant, if the question is really about what you can do with the final string. (Your title talks about "get last duplicate element in a list" but it's really "get the last element of a list represented by a comma-separated string")

Comment: How is the "latest" `access` different from the first? Its the same string, or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be use the Index of the item in original collection along with GroupBy. For example,

```
    var lastDistinct = filterList.Select((x,index)=> new {Value=x,Index=index})
                                 .GroupBy(x=>x.Value)
                                 .Select(x=> x.Last())
                                 .OrderBy(x=>x.Index)
                                 .Select(x=>x.Value);
    var result = string.Join(",",lastDistinct);
```

Output

```
access,postpone,success
```

Comment: Appreciate with the nice example. Helping so much.

Answer (score 1):

An OrderedDictionary does this. All you have to do is add your items to it with a logic of "if it's in the dictionary, remove it. add it". OrderedDictionary preserves the order of adding so by removing an earlier added one and re-adding it it jumps to the end of the dictionary

```
var d = new OrderedDictionary();
filterList.ForEach(x => { if(d.Contains(x)) d.Remove(x); d[x] = null; });
```

Your `d.Keys` is now a list of strings

```
access
postpone
success
```

OrderedDictionary is in the `Collections.Specialized` namespace

If you wanted the keys as a CSV, you can use `Cast` to turn them from object to string

```
var s = string.Join(",", d.Keys.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation..... I had learn the new thing 'OrderedDictionary'.

Answer (score 0):

Your input list is only of type string, so using groupBy doesn't really add anything. If you consider your code, your first line gives you the distinct list, you only lose the distinct items because you did a string.join on line 2. All you need to do is add a line before you join:

```
List<string> filter = filterList.Distinct().ToList();
string last = filter.LastOrDefault();
string a = string.Join(",", filter.Select(a => a).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

I suppose you could make your code more terse because you need neither .Select(a => a) nor .ToArray() in your call to string.Join.

GroupBy would be used if you had a list of class/struct/record/tuple items, where you might want to group by a specific key (or keys) rather than using Distinct() on the whole thing. GroupBy is very useful and you should learn that, and also the ToDictionary and ToLookup LINQ helper functionality.

Answer (score 0):

So why shouldn't you return the first occurrence of "postpone"? Because later in the sequence you see the same word "postpone" again. Why would you return the first occurrence of "access"? Because later in the sequence you don't see this word anymore.

So: return a word if the rest of the sequence does not have this word.

This would be easy in LINQ, with recursion, but it is not very efficient: for every word you would have to check the rest of the sequence to see if the word is in the rest.

It would be way more efficient to remember the highest index on which you found a word.

As an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp).

```
private static IEnumerable<T> FindLastOccurences<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return FindLastOccurrences<T>(source, null);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindLastOccurences<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    // TODO: check source not null
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    Dictionary<T, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);

    int index = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        // did we already see this T? = is this in the dictionary
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out int highestIndex))
        {
            // we already saw it at index highestIndex.
            dictionary[item] = index;
        }
        else
        {
            // it is not in the dictionary, we never saw this item.
            dictionary.Add(item, index);
        }
        ++index;
    }

    // return the keys after sorting by value (which contains the highest index)
    return dictionay.OrderBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
                    .Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key);
}
```

So for every item in the source sequence, we check if it is in the dictionary. If not, we add the item as key to the dictionary. The value is the index.

If it is already in the dictionary, then the value was the highest index of where we found this item before. Apparently the current index is higher, so we replace the value in the dictionary.

Finally we order the key value pairs in the dictionary by ascending value, and return only the keys.